# Go fun the world - is it correct?

Tags: punctuation, omissibility

I want to know if 9Gag slogan "Go fun the world" is correct or not.
I know that it is ok to say "Let's go have fun" but the slogan above misses "have". Is it ok?

One more - is "word" addressee there? If yes, why it is not separated by commas "Go fun, the world"?

Is ok to say: "Let's go fun, guys!" as the offer to go have fun to the friends?
Thanks for the answers

Comment: 'Fun' was apparently a transitive verb before it was a noun, but is only used colloquially as such now ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fun)). This may be found by looking up << fun + verb >>. 'Fun the world' is a tongue-in-cheek usage. The "Go take a hike!", "Go fly a kite!" style of expression, probably best analysed as an imperative 'go shopping / hunting / dancing ...' phase construction, is well known.

Comment: It looks to me like a play on words, referencing the informal "go f---- _something_", by replacing the usual verb with a north-americanism (that Is, it _is_ accepted as a verb there) that begins with the same sound. I did not think it was idiomatic until I read its entry at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fun , and I suggest that you should be careful with any of this sort of wordplay on vulgarisms - it can be offensive.

Comment: Oh, in other words "Go fun the world" means "Let's laugh at the world". That's the reason it is not separated by commas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Don’t you think that by now the habit of using verbs as nouns and nouns as transitive has reached a point where there is license to anybody to use ‘fun’ to have the meaning “make the world have fun”?  (which would not make as effective copy)

Comment: @Tuffy I have no desire to Tuffy the world. But 'fun' (the verb) is defined by Wiktionary as 'make fun of' / 'poke fun at' (colloquial), and that's the sense I'm aware of. Perhaps one should say the default.

Answer (score 1):

"Fun The world" was officially a Tagline used by 9 Gags. It's  satirical Form of Saying Fuck the world.

Now if you are intending to use the phrase Go,  the World, Anything that you use post the Comma are Typically Verb Forms being used in their Present Tense.